# "unknown operation ssh" while checking status of ssh service

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm trying to start SSH service on my virtual linux machine.

But getting "unknown operation" error while I'm trying to check service status

```
sudo service start ssh

sudo systemctl ssh status
```

"unknown operation ssh"

Comment: SO is for programming questions only, so OS/app support is [off-topic](/help/on-topic). You could ask on [ubuntu.se] instead, but where this is basically a typo, I wouldn't bother.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command arguments are in the wrong order in both cases, I think you inverted the CLI usage

With the service CLI you would get :

```sh
sudo service ssh status
```

And with systemctl :

```sh
sudo systemctl status ssh
```

The usage is described like this from systemctl manpage :

```
systemctl [OPTIONS...] COMMAND [NAME...]
```

Your command here is `status` and the name of the service is `ssh`